# Updating Stripe metadata example

Tags: metadata, stripe-payments

Is it possible to update subscription' metadata after it was created ?

For example change some Ids or other related information

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can certainly update metadata on a Subscription object. Simply retrieve the Subscription and add or edit any metadata properties. Things such as the subscription's id, however, are immutable and not something a user can define.

```
sub = stripe.Subscription.retrieve("sub_xxxxxyyyyzzzz")
sub.metadata['order_id'] = "A1234"
sub.save()
```

https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update?lang=python#update_subscription-metadata